# How do I minimize a maximized window?

Tags: unity, gnome, mouse

When I open, for example, `firefox` and maximise the window, I'm unable to minimise or close the window using the little `x` button in the top left.

Here's the button that I *want* to press (it appears when I move my mouse up to the toolbar, as if I'm about to click `file` or `edit`, etc.):

[image]

But when I move my mouse over to the left, it turns into this (there's nothing to click on, the button disappears!):

[image]

In order to actually close or minimise the window I have to double-click the toolbar at the top to make it "not maximised", and then I can click the buttons. What's going on here?

I'm running `ubuntu 14.04` with proprietary ATI drivers.

Comment: I know it's not an answer, but I'm fond of using the keyboard shortcuts, either `Ctrl-Q` or `Ctrl-W`, which in your case would do.

Comment: when you move the upper left corner, it disappears? That's not how it is supposed to be. Silly question, but did you try restart?

Answer (score 0):

Quant, just click twice on the toolbar any where in the middle like you click for opening a file or folder. Thereafter do what you had been trying to do, I mean go to the left side of the toolbar and there you found the three buttons will be working.

Answer (score 0):

Try in terminal:

> `killall unity-panel-service`

and see if they work.
You can also press right button on the title to get those commands aswell.

If that won't help, this could be something with your screen resolution. Try changing and see if they work.